# Mysql code runs but the foreign key values are not showing in table

Tags: php, mysql

My code runs in phpmyadmin but the foreign key values are not showing in table and when I update it the message shows "0 rows affected"

my table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE fee_report (
fr_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
school_id INT NOT NULL,
branch_id INT NOT NULL,
student_id INT NOT NULL,
ledger VARCHAR(55),
bill_no VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
fdate date NOT NULL,
receipt_no VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
dr float NOT NULL,
cr float NOT NULL,
balance float NOT NULL,
particulars VARCHAR(155),
updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_frschool FOREIGN KEY (school_id)
REFERENCES school(school_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_frbranch FOREIGN KEY (branch_id)
REFERENCES branch(branch_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_frstudent FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
REFERENCES student(student_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


INSERT INTO fee_report(school_id,branch_id,student_id,ledger,bill_no,fdate,dr,balance,particulars,feetype) 
VALUES(1,1,13,'TGS007','SESNOV1020',CURDATE(),'2850','-14450','11','Tuition Fee,Transport Fee,Smart Class Fee,SA-1 Exam Fee')
```

Why foreign keys school_id, branch_id and student_id are not showing in table
and when I remove foreign key constraint the values are visible in table

Comment: I don't think we can help you unless you show your table definition, including primary keys, foreign keys, and indexes.

Comment: If you have foreign key constraint and those values are not in the origin table then the insert won't be possible. Is the value 1 in the school_id column in school table? same question for branch and student.

Comment: Yes the value 1 in the school_id column in school table? same question for branch and student

Comment: I have updated my question with table schema please see

Comment: it looks like you are not setting any values for your three foreign keys in your insert.